# Passing a complex objects array from client to server WITHOUT ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a form that I would like the users to submit to the server.
The (simplified) model looks like that:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ComplexObject> MyArray { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexObject
{
    public int MyComplexObjectInt { get; set; }
    public string MyComplexObjectString { get; set; }
}
```

The controller action that receives this object looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyData model)
{
    ...
}
```

I have a "ComplexObject" array in the client side (jQuery) that I populate with user's input.

**The problem:** How can I set the "MyArray" value to contain the jQuery array values and retrieve this array in the controller?

Note: I've googled this issue quite a bit and all the solutions I've found talked about ajax. I'm not interesting in these solutions and I wonder if it can be done without ajax.

Thanks.

Comment: If something can be done with AJAX it can be done using a standard POST or GET request just as well. If your endpoint is `process.aspx` you just need to use `<form action="process.aspx">` instead of `$.ajax('process.aspx')`.

Comment: @pawel ok, so how can I take this jquery array and pass it on to the controller along with the other model fields ("MyInt" in my case)?

Comment: Something along these lines: `<input type="hidden" name="MyInt" value="<%= MyInt %>"> <input type="hidden" name="ComplexObject" value="" />`, then set the value of ComplexObject input to `JSON.stringify( jQueryArray )` before submitting the form.

Comment: @pawel - I was hoping for another solution, but ended up with yours. please post an answer so I can accept. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something can be done with AJAX it can be done using a standard POST or GET request just as well. If your endpoint is process.aspx you just need to use `<form action="process.aspx">` instead of `$.ajax('process.aspx')`.

So if you need to get some data from your backend, combine it with user-provided data then process it on the server with a full round-trip (not AJAX) you can use a form and hidden inputs:

```
<form action="process.aspx" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="MyInt" value="<%= MyInt %>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="ComplexObject"   value="" />
</form>
```

Then when you need to send the `ComplexObject` along with `MyInt`, you can serialize that object as JSON string, put it into the hidden field and submit the form:

```
$('[name="ComplexObject"]').val( JSON.stringify( userObject ) );
$('#myform').submit();
```

Comment: Simple but good, thank you!